# random walk python implementation

Tags: igraph, random-walk

Hello there is a python implementation of igraph_random_walk available in the r version?

If is not available How can I easly develop one random walk function using igraph?

Hope someone will help me.

Answer (score 0):

There seems not to be a Python equivalent implementation.
But you can easily implement it on your own. Take the same method signature

`random_walk(graph, start, steps, mode = c("out", "in", "all"), stuck = c("return", "error"))`

(or simplify it to your needs) and use the [random package](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html), e.g.

```
random.randint(1, n_neighbors)
```

where `n_neighbors` is the number of neighbors the current node has. Then move on to the chosen node and call the same function recursively with `steps-1`.